# HBASE shell script that fails using ARGV

Tags: ruby, shell, hbase

I am running the following HBASE shell script that fails, and I can't figure out why:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.CompareFilter
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.SubstringComparator
a = ARGV[0]
myscan="'dcqa_event_agg', {FILTER => org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.RowFilter.new(CompareFilter::CompareOp.valueOf('EQUAL'),SubstringComparator.new('" + a + "'))}" + "\n"
scan myscan
exit
```

The dcqa_event_agg row exists. When I run the command:

```
hbase shell filtertest.rb 2013
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Unknown table 'dcqa_event_agg', {FILTER => org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.RowFilter.new(CompareFilter::CompareOp.valueOf('EQUAL'),SubstringComparator.new('2013'))}
```

When I run the script directly in the HBASE shell, it works fine. Any ideas?

I added some debugging to the shell script:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.CompareFilter
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.SubstringComparator
a = ARGV[0]
myscan="'dcqa_event_agg', {FILTER => org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.RowFilter.new(CompareFilter::CompareOp.valueOf('EQUAL'),SubstringComparator.new('" + a + "'))}"
print myscan + "\n"
print "scan " + myscan + "\n"
scan myscan
exit
```

this is the output:

```
[test ~]$ hbase shell filtertest.rb 2013
13/08/23 18:08:44 WARN conf.Configuration: hadoop.native.lib is deprecated. Instead, use io.native.lib.available
'dcqa_event_agg', {FILTER => org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.RowFilter.new(CompareFilter::CompareOp.valueOf('EQUAL'),SubstringComparator.new('2013'))}
scan 'dcqa_event_agg', {FILTER => org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.RowFilter.new(CompareFilter::CompareOp.valueOf('EQUAL'),SubstringComparator.new('2013'))}
ERROR: Unknown table 'dcqa_event_agg', {FILTER => org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.RowFilter.new(CompareFilter::CompareOp.valueOf('EQUAL'),SubstringComparator.new('2013'))}!
```

Removing the quotes didn't fix it.

If I run the commands in the hbase shell environment:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.CompareFilter
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.SubstringComparator
scan 'dcqa_event_agg', {FILTER => org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.RowFilter.new(CompareFilter::CompareOp.valueOf('EQUAL'),SubstringComparator.new('2013'))}
```

I don't get the error.

Comment: Post the shell command that works.  You might try removing the quotes around dcqa_event_agg or 2013.

Comment: Removing the quotes didn't work. I edited the original question to add some debugging.

Answer (score 0):

The second arguments is `Hash`, not `String`.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.CompareFilter
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.SubstringComparator
a = ARGV[0]
scan 'dcqa_event_agg', {FILTER => org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.RowFilter.new(CompareFilter::CompareOp.valueOf('EQUAL'),SubstringComparator.new('#{a}'))}
exit
```